# Identify error in how the pointers are handled

Tags: c++, pointers

The question want me to identify the error in how the pointers are handled.
I tried compiling it but it doesn't give any error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *ptr = new int;
  int *ptr2 = ptr;
  delete ptr;
  ptr = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect an error from the code you show? What kind of error do you expect?

Comment: Why do you think this shouldn't compile?  If you want to avoid cases where you have a pointer to deleted memory then you should use smart pointers

Comment: This code is wrong and cannot compile. How do you compile this? What is your platform? Which IDE do you use? Which compiler do you use? What do _you_ think is wrong with this code?

Comment: Is this your homework? Try doing something with the pointers before and after the delete/NULLing. Also, run the code. Just because it compiles doesn't mean it works. And just because it works doesn't mean it does anything useful.

Comment: the lack of int main() is just error on my part. fixed the question. I am able to compile the code using mingw compiler.

Not my homework. Past years question that I'm using to study.

Comment: @AlifAbdulRahman It doesn't give you an error because there is no error to report in the provided code.

Comment: Do _you_ think there is a problem with this code? Whatever you think, you should let us know what _you_ think and then we can give you an answer or at least some advice.

Comment: If you use `ptr2` after the `delete`, there will be problems.  Since you don't use `ptr2`, there are no problems with your code.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you miss "int main()" line

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int *ptr = new int;
  int *ptr2 = ptr;
  delete ptr;
  ptr = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your code in a `main` method and compile it `valgrid` is not giving you any error. What are you looking for?

> valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
>
> ==22277== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>
> ==22277== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>
> ==22277== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>
> ==22277== Command: ./a.out
>
> ==22277==
>
> ==22277==
>
> ==22277== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==22277==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==22277==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated
>
> ==22277==
>
> ==22277== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>
> ==22277==
>
> ==22277== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==22277== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 8 from 6)

Comment: It won't give an error because number of news == number of deletes. But if you try to use one of the pointers, especially the one that was assigned and didn't get NULLed....